# Having issues decompiling *any* class with Jode

Tags: java, decompiler

I've been staring at this issue for hours now.  Any help is appreciated.

I wrote code that uses the Jode decompiler from the "embedded jode jar file".  I want to use this version because it is under the Lesser GNU Public License.

```
Decompiler d = new Decompiler();
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("c:\\jode.txt");

    d.setClassPath("C:\\mycode");

    ProgressListener p = new ProgressListener() {

        public void updateProgress(double arg0, String arg1) {
            System.out.println("inside of progress listener with arg0 = " +arg0+ " and arg1 = " +arg1);
        }
    };

    d.decompile("Test.class" , fw, p);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

and I always get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test.class
        at jode.bytecode.ClassInfo.loadInfo(ClassInfo.java:620)
        at jode.decompiler.ClassAnalyzer.<init>(ClassAnalyzer.java:86)
        at jode.decompiler.ClassAnalyzer.<init>(ClassAnalyzer.java:123)
        at jode.decompiler.Decompiler.decompile(Decompiler.java:191)
        at testdecompiler.Main.main(Main.java:45)
```

If I use

```
jode.decompiler.Main.decompile(...)
```

things work - but I can't use this class file because it resides in the jode.jar that is only GPL.

Comment: I have also run d.decompile("Test", fw, p), omitting the .class, still fails.

Comment: By the way: Main.decompile sets the classpath and boot classpath according to the system properties. Maybe Vladimir Dyuzhev is right about adding rt.jar to your cp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem with all of the different binary versions of jode that are available from their web site.  When I built a new version of jode using the mainline from svn, it worked fine.  I also saw an entry in one of the jode forums where a user was complaining about the NoClassDefFound problem.  His case sounded slightly different, but the jode developer suggested that he use the mainline from svn instead of the prebuild binary.

Comment: How did you get the mainline from SVN?  On Jode's page, if I follow the link from the following text : "You can get the latest sources from the  CVS repository. Follow the instruction on that page; use jode as modulename. If you want to checkout a specific version you can use the -r option:", I essentially get a 404.

Comment: Go to the jode page on sourceforge and click the Develop tab (or go straight to http://sourceforge.net/projects/jode/develop where you will find the svn information.

Answer (score 0):

```
d.setClassPath("C:\\mycode");
```

This classpath looks awfully short to me.

Comment: Hi Vladimir,
  Yes, it's not the real value of the classpath, because I don't want to advertise it here.  I basically set it to a string that points to the location of the class file being decompiled.  Is that correct?

Comment: What I mean is that NoClassDefFound can be not the topmost one. If a class your class depends upon cannot be found, you can get NoClassDefFound despite your class IS in the classpath. Your classpath, I believe, should contain at least JRE rt.jar. Possibly, I'd took my own process classpath, appended your test dir (semicolon-separated, according to Javadoc), and use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Update: My original assumption was wrong, and to bad, the original exception/ message is thrown away, as far a i can see. The code where JODE fails looks like this:

```
 try {
      DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream
          (new BufferedInputStream
           (classpath.getFile(name.replace('.', '/') + ".class")));
        read(input, howMuch);            

  } catch (IOException ex) {
        String message = ex.getMessage();
      if ((howMuch & ~(FIELDS|METHODS|HIERARCHY
                       |INNERCLASSES|OUTERCLASSES)) != 0) {
          throw new NoClassDefFoundError(name);
        }
```

Since an IOException has to be thrown to get the NoClassDefFound, check anything regarding your IO subsytsem, e.g. the file.encoding. I guess you should patch JODE to get the detailed error message or debug to this point.

Comment: I think we answered the same thing, in the same time..that is "remove the ".class" suffix :-))

Comment: I'm using jode-1.1-embedded.jar from sourceforge.  I tried omitting the ".class", as well as using forward slashes (in windows it would be : d.setClassPath("C://mycode"); -- Still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, as i don't fancy myself with decompiling classes, but i think that u should use

```
d.decompile("Test" , fw, p);
```

instead of what u are using now. This could be similar to

```
Class.forName("ClassName")
```

without the "class" suffix.

Comment: I've tried this, as I pointed out in the comment to my original post, and it did not work.  Has anyone had any success trying this on their own?

Comment: Without knowing implementation details, it's hard to give an answer, but surely, the problem is that your "Test.class" param is NOT correct. As @dz suggested, u should investigate further at jode.bytecode.ClassInfo.loadInfo() or jode.decompiler.Decompiler.decompile() to see what's missing. Is it possible to debug?

Comment: I can't seem to decompile it.  I have the sources and the class files, but when I step into the decompile function I don't jump into any sources.  I think the debug symbols may have been stripped?

Comment: CORRECTION in last comment, I can't seem to debug it.

Comment: Jad is newer, I believe. At least I always use Jad. But it's a C++ application, of course...